# How does GROUP BY use COUNT(*)

Tags: sql

I have this query which finds the number of properties handled by each staff member along with their branch number:

```
SELECT s.branchNo, s.staffNo, COUNT(*) AS myCount
FROM Staff s, PropertyForRent p
WHERE s.staffNo=p.staffNo
GROUP BY s.branchNo, s.staffNo
```

The two relations are:

```
Staff{staffNo, fName, lName, position, sex, DOB, salary, branchNO}
PropertyToRent{propertyNo, street, city, postcode, type, rooms, rent, ownerNo, staffNo, branchNo}
```

How does SQL know what `COUNT(*)` is referring to? Why does it count the number of properties and not (say for example), the number of staff per branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit long for a comment.

`COUNT(*)` is counting the number of rows in each group.  It is not specifically counting any particular column.  Instead, what is happening is that the `join` is producing multiple properties, because the properties are what cause multiple rows for given values of `s.branchNo` and `s.staffNo`.

It gets even a little more "confusing" if you include a column name.  The following would all typically return the same value:

```
COUNT(*)
COUNT(s.branchNo)
COUNT(s.staffNo)
COUNT(p.propertyNo)
```

With a column name, `COUNT()` determines the number of rows that do not have a `NULL` value in the column.

And finally, you should learn to use proper, explicit `join` syntax in your queries.  Put `join` conditions in the `on` clause, not the `where` clause:

```
SELECT s.branchNo, s.staffNo, COUNT(*) AS myCount
FROM Staff s JOIN
     PropertyForRent p
     ON s.staffNo = p.staffNO
GROUP BY s.branchNo, s.staffNo;
```

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP BY` clauses partition your result set. These partitions are all the sql engine needs to know - it simply counts their sizes.

Try your query with only `count(*)` in the `select` part.

In particular, `COUNT(*)` does *not* produce the number of distinct rows/columns in your result set!

Answer (score 0):

Some people might think that `count(*)` really count all the columns, however the sql `optimizer` is smarter than that.

`COUNT(*)` returns the number of rows in a specified table without getting rid of duplicates. Which mean that you can't use `Distinct` with `count(*)`

`Count(*)` will return the cardinality (elements in table) of the specified mapping.

What you have to remember is that when using `count` over a specific column, `null` won't be allowed while `count(*)` will allow null in the rows as it could be any field.

> How does SQL know what COUNT(*) is referring to?

I'm pretty sure, however not 100% sure as I can't find in doc, that the `sql optimizer` simply do a count on the `primary key` (not null) instead of trying to handle `null` in rows.